# What does it mean `Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.`

Tags: typescript

I have the following code and `noImplicitAny:true` in `tsconfig`:

```
let o = {a: 3};

// works fine
o['a'] = 3;

// reports an error 
// Error:(4, 1) TS7017:Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
o['b'] = 3;
```

What does this error mean?

[Here it is on the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20o%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%203%7D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20works%20fine%0Ao%5B'a'%5D%20%3D%203%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20reports%20an%20error%20%0A%2F%2F%20Error%3A(4%2C%201)%20TS7017%3AIndex%20signature%20of%20object%20type%20implicitly%20has%20an%20'any'%20type.%0Ao%5B'b'%5D%20%3D%203%3B) - be sure to click Options and set `noImplicitAny` (doesn't seem to remember options in shareable links).

Comment: If I change the first line to `let o = {b: 3};` it complains about the `o['a'] = 3;` line instead. So it appears to trigger only when using brackets notation to set a property the object doesn't have or when using a name it can't resolve at compile-time (since it also complains about `o[Math.random()] = 3;`).

Comment: yeah, it is triggered only when accessing properties using brackets. To suppress the warning, one can use `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true`, but I'm trying to understand why the error is there in the first place. This is error is different from `Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: number; }'.` if `o.b=3`

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Very strange.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, are you learning `TS` as well? :)

Comment: I'm involved in my first TypeScript project, yes. But mostly I just found the question really interesting. :-)

Comment: I see, me as well. First angular2 app

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error is caused because the [index signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#394-index-signatures) is not explicitly defined.

You can declare an `index signature` explicitly like so:

```
let ox : { [index:string] : number } = {};
ox['b'] = 3;
```

The reason `o['a'] = 3;` doesn't error is because of rule 1 of bracket notation property access which is defined in the following [rules from the spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#413-property-access):

> 1. If index is a string literal or a numeric literal and object has an apparent property (section 3.11.1) with the name given by that literal (converted to its string representation in the case of a numeric literal), the property access is of the type of that property.
> 2. Otherwise, if object has an apparent numeric index signature and index is of type Any, the Number primitive type, or an enum type, the property access is of the type of that index signature.
> 3. Otherwise, if object has an apparent string index signature and index is of type Any, the String or Number primitive type, or an enum type, the property access is of the type of that index signature.
> 4. Otherwise, if index is of type Any, the String or Number primitive type, or an enum type, the property access is of type Any.
> 5. Otherwise, the property access is invalid and a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: thanks, what `property access` in _the property access is of the type of that property_ ?

Comment: @Maximus I've corrected the answer. I'm still not sure why the error doesn't happen for the first example, but I think it's due to bracket notation

Comment: thanks, but it's still unclear what is `property access`

Comment: I wish I could have found this answer 6 hours ago. Just to add for completeness, the mentioned spec is pretty outdated, you can take a look at the latest documentation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types too bad that the documentation is put in the interface section, while in fact indexable type could be anything from object literal to array and has nothing to do with interface, that's why I couldn't find this documentation earlier.

Comment: @HendraUzia the linked spec is from the source code, so it should be the latest. The handbook is more accessable though. See here for more info - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/doc